# Проблема с ДЖЕНЕРИКАМИ

Tags: java, generics

Помогите мучает вопрос, есть абстрактный класс с одним абстрактным методом:

```
public abstract class AbstractDTO {
    private long id;

    public abstract  <T extends AbstractEntity> void convertListToDTO(List<T> entityList);
}
```

Есть наследник, где Client наследуется от AbstractEntity:

```
public class ClientDTO extends AbstractDTO{

    public void convertListToDTO(List<Client> clients) {

    }
}
```

Но такая запись выдает ошибку:

> both methods have same erasure

Исправляю на такую запись

```
public abstract class AbstractDTO <T extends AbstractEntity> {
    private long id;

     abstract void convertListToDTO(List<T> entityList);
}
```

И у наследника:

```
public class ClientDTO extends AbstractDTO<Client>{

    public void convertListToDTO(List<Client> clients) {

    }
```

Так работает. В чем причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом варианте вы объявляете абстрактный генерик метод, а во втором - абстрактный генерик класс. Объявление генерик метода в наследнике, в первом варианте, должно быть таким:

```
    @Override
    public <T extends AbstractEntity> void convertListToDTO(List<T> entityList) {
       // какой-то код
    }
```

Такое объявление ограничивает `T` внутри типа аргумента `List<T> entityList`. То есть, если у вас есть классы:

```
class Client extends AbstractEntity {

}

class Client2 extends Client {

}

class Client3 {

}
```

то `T` может быть `Client` или `Client2`, но не `Client3`:

```
    ClientDTO dto = new ClientDTO();
    List<Client> list = new ArrayList<>();
    dto.convertListToDTO(list);
```

компилируется

```
    ClientDTO dto = new ClientDTO();
    List<Client2> list = new ArrayList<>();
    dto.convertListToDTO(list);
```

компилируется

```
    ClientDTO dto = new ClientDTO();
    List<Client3> list = new ArrayList<>();
    dto.convertListToDTO(list);
```

не компилируется

Ваша же попытка объявить метод `public void convertListToDTO(List<Client> clients)` воспринимается как попытка объявить **другой** метод. Но поскольку генериков в рантайме нет, то оба метода получат одну и ту же сигнатуру `convertListToDTO(List)`, на что компилятор и ругается.

Answer (score 1):

Обобщения в Java реализуются с использованием стирания (aka erasure). Иначе говоря, при использовании обобщения любая конкретная информация о типе теряется.

В этом можно убедиться из примера:

```java
Class c1 = new ArrayList<String>().getClass();
Class c2 = new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass();
System.out.println(c1 == c2); // output: true
```

Стирания не являются особенностью языка. Скорее это компромисс в реализации обобщений Java, неизбежный из-за того, что обобщения не были частью языка с самого начала.

**Обобщенные типы присутствуют только во время статической проверки типов**, после которой **каждый обобщенный тип в программе стирается**, то есть заменяется необобщенным верхним ограничением.

Например, обозначение вида `List<T>` стирается до `List`, а переменные обычных типов стираются до `Object` (если не задано ограничение!).

Основная причина для применения стирания заключается в том, что оно позволяет использовать обобщенный клиентский код с не обобщенными библиотеками, и наоборот.

Это обстоятельство часто называется **«Миграционной совместимостью»**

Иными словами, даже если программисты будут писать только обобщенный код, им придется иметь дело с не обобщенными библиотеками, написанными до *Java SE5* (появление Generics).

Взяв все это во внимание, можно предположить, что методы `convertListToDTO` в обоих классах будут иметь одну и ту же сигнатуру, так как дженерики стираются. Может показаться, что все нормально, но следует учитывать, что дженерики - инвариантны. Если приводить пример, то `List <Integer>` — это `List<Integer>` и ничего больше.

Таким образом, в первом варианте у вас `<T extends AbstractEntity>`, который не эквивалентен `Client` - следовательно, вы создаете другой метод, но из-за стирания у них оказывается одинаковая сигнатура.

Во втором случае, вы уже определяете `T` как `Client`, поэтому вы просто переопределяете метод, что не приводит к ошибкам.